# Auto post on Facebook wall whit python

Tags: python, facebook, facebook-graph-api, bots

I tried to make a script that can automatically post on the wall of Facebook, this:

```
import facebook

graph = facebook.GraphAPI(access_token='...')

attachment =  {
    'name': 'Link name',
    'link': 'http://www.example.com/',
    'caption': 'Check out this example',
    'description': 'This is a longer description of the attachment',
    'picture': 'https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/c/c4/Michelangelo_Merisi_da_Caravaggio_-_Medusa.png',
}

graph.put_wall_post(message='Check this out...', attachment=attachment)
```

but unfortunately give me this error, I do not know where the problem is ...

```
`AttributeError: 'GraphAPI' object has no attribute 'put_wall_post'
```

Comment: The answer to your question is in the error message. The `GraphAPI` object doesn't have a method called `put_wall_post`. Which version of the SDK are you using?

Comment: i have the V 2.0.0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Use put_object**

> Writes the given object to the graph, connected to the given parent.
>
> Parameters
>
> parent_object – A string that is a unique ID for that particular
>   resource. The parent_object is the parent of a connection or edge.
>   E.g., profile is the parent of a feed, and a post is the parent of a
>   comment. connection_name - A string that specifies the connection or
>   edge between objects, e.g., feed, friends, groups, likes, posts.
>   Examples

```
# Write 'Hello, world' to the active user's wall.
 graph.put_object(parent_object='me', connection_name='feed',
                  message='Hello, world')

# Add a link and write a message about it.
graph.put_object(
   parent_object="me",
   connection_name="feed",
   message="This is a great website. Everyone should visit it.",
   link="https://www.facebook.com")

 # Write a comment on a post.
 graph.put_object(parent_object='post_id', connection_name='comments',
                  message='First!')
```

Is it your page? You need to be the administrator of the page to be able to post to the news feed. Otherwise, you can only submit a post to the "posts to page" part of the page.  Make sure the user account has been configured as a 'Admin' and not as 'Moderator'.

Check the roles here:

https://developers.facebook.com/docs/pages/access-tokens#roles

Answer (score 0):

Your code should work for V2.0.0 of the facebook SDK, but the latest version uses the `put_object` method. See the [documentation](http://facebook-sdk.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html) for details on how to use it.

Comment: facebook.GraphAPIError: (#200) Requires either publish_actions permission, or manage_pages and publish_pages as an admin with sufficient administrative permission

Comment: now i have this error, i refresh the token whit the permission, but nothing

Comment: You'll likely need to get a token with the correct permissions. The error being thrown says you do not have the correct permissions, so that is most likely the issue.